# Terminal error: i2c i2c-0 sendbytes error -110

Tags: 12.04, command-line, server

I am currently using a clean installation of Ubuntu Server 12.04 AMD64 and I keep getting errors popping up saying:

> [ xxx.xxxx ] i2c i2c-0: sendbytes: error -110

where x is the seconds the server has been online. The server appears to run fine apart from this. I could put up with it but it's very intrusive in that it writes over the top of my command that I am typing or file that I am editing. It doesnt affect the data underneath but I can no longer see what I am typing.

Does anyone know what this is related to? I've searched online but come up with nothing except that it is *possibly* related to a kernal bug.

Other details that may be important:

- After running aptitude update and aptitude upgrade, error still persists
- 4GB of RAM
- Ran a memory checker for 12 hours, about 6 full checks and no errors
- Roughly 30GB of space available for Ubuntu on my SSD
- Solid State also has Windows 7 on it

> sda1 Windows System Reserved
>  sda2 Windows7
>  sda5 Ubuntu
>   Server
>  sda6 Ubuntu Swap

*Edit: I've noticed that I dont get the error messages through SSH, this leads me to believe that it is either in response to my USB keyboard or that SSH filters out these messages. While using SSH does solve the issue of these annnoying messages, it would still be nice to know the root cause of them.*